# OpenSUSE LEAP 15.1 installer shuts down during install

Tags: installation, opensuse

I've tried to install OpenSUSE LEAP 15.1 from a bootable USB on my laptop (Dell xps-15 9560).  I select the Install option and it runs for a while displaying a green bar, but then it shuts the laptop down.

Is there a way to get OpenSUSE past this problem?  Would an earlier version solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Geez, you can't win for losing.  I've occasionally run into this with a particular PC that apparently has some hardware component that gives multiple distros indigestion (OpenSUSE was one of those).  If Ubuntu was working before the upgrade (your previous question), consider installing the current LTS release (18.04).  The interim releases are a bit like beta testing and can be buggy.  Unless you have a specific need for the latest features Canonical is testing for future releases, there typically isn't a good reason to mess with the interim releases.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips for the 9560 on OpenSUSE LEap 15.1.

To fix the shutdown problem you need to add the kernel parameter:
acpi=off

during installation to boot the 9560. Remove this again after installation.

The touchpad also won't work, so to fix this add the kernel parameter:
i8042.reset

For HiDPI I recommend to update to the newest Plasma and set display scaling to 225%.

There also seem to be some power-consumption issues with the nVidia chip active, so follow instructions at https://github.com/openSUSE/SUSEPrime to fix with the nVidia prorietary G05 driver and DynamicPowerManagement.